# innerHTML size limit

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

I want to use AJAX to load an htmlfile into a `<div>`  I will then need to run jsMath on this.  Everything I have done so far with innerHTML has been a paragraph or two, maybe a table and/or image. Nothing too fancy.

What potential problems may occur when I set innerHTML to an external 25k file, with all sorts of complex css formatting?  (thanks to jsMath)  I can't think of any other method of doing this, but need to know if there are any limitations.

Thanks in advance.

--Dave

Comment: Just a reminder, you should accept answers to your questions.  It's the SO way.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about any browser specific size limits, but if you assign a string longer that 65536, Chrome splits it into many `elem.childNodes`, so you might have to loop over these nodes and concatenate them.

Run the below snipped in Chrome Dev Tools. It constructs a 160k string, but `theDivElement.childNodes[0]` gets clipped to 65536 chars.

```
var longString = '1234567890';
for (var i = 0; i < 14; ++i) {
  longString = longString + longString;
}
console.log('The length of our long string: ' + longString.length);
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = longString;
var innerHtmlValue = elem.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log('The length as innerHTML-childNodes[0]: ' + innerHtmlValue.length);
console.log('Num child nodes: ' + elem.childNodes.length);
```

Result: (Chrome version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit), Linux Mint 17)

```
The length of our long string: 163840
The length as innerHTML-childNodes[0]: 65536
Num child nodes: 3
```

But in Firefox, `innerHTML` doesn't split the contents into many nodes: (Firefox version 34.0, Linux Mint 17)

```
"The length of our long string: 163840"
"The length as innerHTML-childNodes[0]: 163840"
"Num child nodes: 1"
```

So you'd need to take into account that different browsers handle `childNodes` differently, and perhaps iterate over all child nodes and concatenate. (I noticed this, because I tried to use `innerHTML` to unescape a > 100k HTML encoded string.)

In fact, in Firefox I can create an `innerHTML-childNodes[0]` of length 167 772 160, by looping to `i < 24` above. But somewhere above this length, there is an `InternalError: allocation size overflow` error.

Comment: Instead of iterating over all child nodes, we can call [node.normalize()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize) method.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to prevent you from doing this technically. The biggest issue will be page load time. Be sure to include some sort of indication that the data is loading or it will look like nothing's happening.

Answer (score 1):

In the application I am currently working on, I have not had any problems in any browser setting innerHTML to a string of 30k or more. (Don't know what the limit is)

Answer (score 0):

The only kind of limits that are on this type of thing are purely bandwidth and processor related. You should make sure you don't have a low timeout set on your ajax request. You should also test on some lower speed computers to see if there is a memory issue. Some old browsers can be pretty unforgiving of large objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to profile this with a tool like [dynatrace ajax](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/pages/) or [speed tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) to understand how setting innerHTML to a really huge value affects performance. You might want to compare it with another approach like putting the new content in an iframe, or paginating the content.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that <i>per se</i>  I'm using AJAX to decide between Chapter 6 review, Chapter 7 review etc, but I hadn't thought to split each review up.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your limit will be most likely the download limit set from your web server. usually a couple of MBs.Several web frameworks allows increasing this size but you cant just do that because that would mean increase buffer size which is not a good thing.