# does .innerhtml have max size?

Tags: jquery

I have following code that is supposed to display product details when clicked on. The data is correctly obtained from the database and i out in alert before invoking the jquery ui dialog and it had the right data.

```
$("body").append('<div id="popup"></div>');

document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML  = "jk;hcjaskda;ldA;LSDMAKDOIDM;A,MCSCM;lc"sac<'LC;MClmca,.c sm,vnkdc ADVdL:VadMVa;dvadvNsmv S/MV s/vn,Va.<VMA:dvma:DVMa<dv d><v a><d S,CVNDMVaA>VM:LDvm;LVMM,CVMAdv<?.vdm;LDVdvDVadvDVDVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVsvdSV/m,vn,m vmn.,c x V/,.ADMNV/ma,.vm./,vm.,vm,DVkldjfk'ejfwejfqlekfmF;LQEJFQ.L,DK;LKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK'LWKF;PWOJVMWPOV";
$( '#popup').dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    width:500,
    height:500,
    buttons: {
        "Back": function() {
            $('#popup').html('');
            $('#popup').dialog('close');
        }

    }

});
```

The pop up only shows 160 charecters
`jk;hcjaskda;ldA;LSDMAKDOIDM;A,MCSCM;lc"sac<'LC;MClmca,.c sm,vnkdc ADVdL:VadMVa;dvadvNsmv S/MV s/vn,Va.<VMA:dvma:DVMa<dv d><v a><d S,CVNDMVaA>VM:LDvm;LVMM,CVMAdv`

is what is displayed. NOt sure where it is getting truncated. The dialog only shows a H scroll bar

Comment: Most likely the browser sees <?a49128736q2lsklfhlaksjghlakgjashfa> and tries to create an element.

Comment: is this code included in a php file?

Comment: use $('#popup').text('Your text string') instead for starters.  If you're going to use jquery you might as well use it.

Comment: I would suggest that you escape any characters that would break our JavaScript code.

Comment: Well.. It truncates at `<?` which could be getting interpreted by php as a code block. But regardless of whether this is the javascript or your php file, you should be getting syntax errors and it shouldn't work at all..

Answer (score 0):

- `.innerHTML` doesn't have a limitation.
- In your example you have to escape the string before setting it!,
  your script contains many chars that causing syntax errors like `"`
  and it has the tag `<?` as well which is a php or other server side language opening tag.

you can escape these chars using this up to this table: [entity-escape-characters-table](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)

**BTW:** This question is a dublicate of [innerhtml-size-limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956170/innerhtml-size-limit)

Comment: `innerHTML` does have a browser specific size limit, I've tested, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27545633/694469

Comment: I updated my answer — seems there's no limit, but the contents gets split into many `childNoeds[*]` each one limited to 65536 chars.